# Mimic tapply behaviour in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I'm looking to mimic the keeping of factors by `tapply` using `data.table`, for example

```
library(data.table)
amounts <- data.table(year = factor(2014:2017, levels = 2010:2017),
                      amount = 1:4)
tapply(amounts$amount, amounts$year, sum)
```

yields

```
2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 
  NA   NA   NA   NA    1    2    3    4
```

However, the approach using data.table doesn't show the years for which no rows are present:

```
amounts[ , list(sumAmount = sum(amount)), by = year]

   year sumAmount
1: 2014         1
2: 2015         2
3: 2016         3
4: 2017         4
```

Is there a clean way to do this in `data.table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
dcast(amounts, 1 ~ year, value.var = 'amount', sum, drop = FALSE, fill = NA)
```

Comment: If you want to spread over a second column (say `months`), you can do that using `dcast` too, e.g. `amounts[ , month := factor(9:12, levels = 1:12)]; dcast(amounts, month ~ year, value.var = 'amount', sum, drop = FALSE, fill = NA)`.

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way to include missing levels is with a join, I think:

```
amounts[.(levels(year)), on=.(year), list(sumAmount = sum(amount)), by = .EACHI]

   year sumAmount
1: 2010        NA
2: 2011        NA
3: 2012        NA
4: 2013        NA
5: 2014         1
6: 2015         2
7: 2016         3
8: 2017         4
```

Comment: Why would you consider `dcast` not to be idiomatic? Is it because you prefer to keep the data in long format?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes. Variable values in column names are garbage unless you're simply browsing it by eye or printing for publication.